# initialize property in swift with additional values

Tags: swift

is it possible to initialize a property in swift with additional values/properties, e.g. a UIButton, UILabel, ...?

I would love to have something like this:

```
let myLabel = UILabel() {
    font = UIFont(...)
    textColor = ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice feature, available in C# (and probably other languages as well), but unfortunately unavailable in swift - and I can't think of any workaround to mimic that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
func config<T>(obj: T, configure: T -> Void) -> T {
    configure(obj)
    return obj
}

let myLabel = config(UILabel(...)) {
    $0.font = UIFont(...)
    $0.textColor = ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Voted up, but configs is not a verb, and it should return (), not Any.

Comment: @Jessy Making it return `Any` allows for single-expression closures that have a non-`Void` return type, as other types are not implicitly converted to `Void`.

Comment: I don't believe that configure should return anything, but if it must, then you can use another generic parameter type. A tuple with no values is different than void in other languages, in that it is actually a value. Any should be considered useless unless you're working with Objective-C code.

Comment: Why introduce another generic param if it isn't useful? Function types are anyway covariant in their return type, so `T -> Any` matches any function that accepts a `T` (or a superclass of `T`, as the argument types are contra variant), regardless of what it returns. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you're not using the return value of configure for anything, inside config, then you're right. It still seems useless/confusing to me, to allow a return value.

Comment: @Jessy Since Swift 1.2, writing anything else than `Void` has become unnecessary: “Unannotated single-expression closures with non-Void return types can now be used in Void contexts.” :-)

Comment: It's interesting to me that you and Apple are using "Void" instead of "()". Rationale?

Comment: @Jessy Haven't really thought this through. I guess I like it better because there's no way `Void` can be mixed up with an empty parameter list or other. `()` is both a value, a type, and additionally denotes a method call… Slightly overloaded for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that would work but you could try with the didSet method

```
let myLabel = UILabel() {
    didSet {
        myLabel.font = UIFont(...)
        myLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise with a closure that returns a value of the type you declare, and executing it with `()`:

```
let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let theLabel = UILabel()
    theLabel.font = UIFont(...)
    theLabel.textColor = ...
    ...
    return theLabel
}()
```

Note that you have to explicitly declare the value type before the `=`

Comment: By the way it is quite common to use this declaration of constants to define global singleton that have to remain constant during the lifetime of your app. For example a core data helper. Global constants declared as above, are guaranteed to be lazily instantiated.